# Nameserver change jumps back to old nameservers - Cause?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, resolve

Migrated from Server A to Server B from different providers, with different IP's for hostname, nameservers, etc.  I've updated the nameservers for a number of domains, and they seem to be propagating, resolving, etc... for a short period of time, and then later, it looks like some of the domains have "jumped" back to the old nameservers...

Any idea what might be causing this? Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Your nameservers aren't configured correctly.
2. The domain registrars aren't recognising the new nameservers and reverting to the old ones.

Comment: Websites do load on the new server... Is there such a thing as a temporary misconfiguration? o.O

Comment: It's not a matter of whether websites load, it is a matter of whether the root dns servers say that your new domain servers are authorative for that domain. You can use an online tool such as http://network-tools.com/ to determine what the rest of the internet thinks your websites should resolve to

Comment: The other option, is that you forgot to increment the serial when updating the nameservers.

Comment: Some registrars like Dotster require an extra step to sort of "register" a new nameserver into their system for your domain besides just changing it on the at-face webUI for the WHOIS record, this caught me once.

Comment: At this point, I believe it might be a registrar discrepancy... I notice the godaddy domains don't have this problem, but the netfirms do... http://serverfault.com/questions/155432/different-domain-registrars-and-new-nameserver-update-discrepancy